# Angular 8 ng build prod gives errors

Tags: javascript, angular, migration

I recently migrated my project from angular 7 to angular 8. Everything works fine but when I try to ng build prod it, it gives error below

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'Ng2CompleterModule'
Could not resolve @angular/http relative to [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]..

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Timer@1.0.0 ng-high-memory-build-prod: `node --max_old_space_size=8000 
./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Timer@1.0.0 ng-high-memory-build-prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-09T10_06_55_527Z-debug.log
```

I guess the @angular/http module is not there in angular 8 so I have removed it from everywhere still this problem persists. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing a bit of information to really help you, so this is just a guess.

You're using [Ng2CompleterModule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-completer) which is apparently a npm package designed for Angular 2

My bet is that it's this component that causes you issue.

Unfortunately in these kind of cases, when the npm packages is not updated anymore, the only thing you can do is look for an alternative, it's time consuming to have to integrate a new package but that's the only way.

[ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) seems to be good for achieving what ng2completer was doing

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I uninstalled ng2completer and reinstalled it and it worked. Uninstalling was important here because simply updating the package was not working.